# Filling in missing date/times in my pd.date_range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of data which looks like the following:
[image]

I am trying to set a range of the entire month:

`rng = pd.date_range('2016-09-01 00:00:00', '2016-09-30 23:59:58', freq='S')`

But my column of data (above) is missing a few hours, and I am unsure where (since my data is 2 million rows large.

I tried to use the `reindex` command, but it instead seemed to have filled everyhthing with zeroes.

The code that I was using is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df_csv)
rng = pd.date_range('2016-09-01 00:00:00', '2016-09-30 23:59:58', freq='S')
df = df.reindex(rng,fill_value=0.0)
```

How do I properly fill in the missing date/times without filling everything with a 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `date` first, then is possible use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
#cast column date if dtype is not datetime
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.set_index('date').reindex(rng,fill_value=0.0)
```

You get all `NaN` values, because reindexing `int` index by `datetime` values (After using `fill_value=0.0` all `NaN` are replaced to `0.0`).

Also if column `date` is sorted, you can use more general solution with selecting first and last value of column `date`:

```
start_date = df.date.iat[0]
end_date = df.date.iat[-1]
rng = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='S')
```